# I want to display 20 characters in asset name using ellipsis

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ellipsis

[image]

In this image i want to display the asset name up to 20 characters
for example  aaaaaaaaaaaa.....

```
<td className="truncateText">{assetName}</td>
```

i am using css

```
.truncateText{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substr()` method to for it:

```js
<td title={assetName} className="truncateText">
     {assetName.length < 20 ? assetName : assetName.substr(0, 20) + "..."}
</td>
```

**Example: [Expo Snack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kh5vnm)**

Comment: i want to use ellipses

Comment: and i want to show rest of the text in tooltip

Comment: you can use `title` prop

Comment: i have not much reputation for upvoting

Answer (score 1):

This might be unreliable to handle with CSS, because the width of 20 characters would keep changing based on font. I would suggest that you handle it with JS instead. Also, since you want to use Ellipsis, you can insert it via the character code.

```
assetName.length < 20 ? assetName : <span>{assetName.split(0,20)}&#8230;</span>
```

Comment: how i show rest of the strings in tool tip

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript for this:

```
function truncateString(str, length = 50) {
  if (typeof str !== "string" || typeof length !== "number") return str
  return str.length > length ? str.substring(0, length - 1) + "..." : str
}

<td className="truncateText">{truncate(assetName, 20)}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

`text-overflow: ellipsis;` displays all the available text content in the specified width.

if you are specific to 20 character length, go for `substring` method.

```
<td className="truncateText">
    {assetName.length > 20? assetName.substring(0,20) + '...' : assetName}
</td>
```